# How to add @XmlTransient in Hibernate Java obj

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, soap, jaxb

I have a Java bean generated by Hibernate:

I want to make certain fields @XmlTransient so in the XML SOAP Request so the user doesnt have to fill them in like:

```
// Generated Feb 25, 2020 9:19:29 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.1    

String WarriorID = "";
@XmlTransient   
Name name = null;
@XmlTransient
int HPStat = -1;
@XmlTransient
int MPStat = -1;
```

so in my SOAPUI I expect it to appear like

```
<warriorID> </warriorID>
```

where the other fields will not be included/seen.

So I downloaded **xml-apis.jar** from mvnrespository so I can call upon this annotation.

The problem is after including the xml-apis.jar in my BuildPath, Eclipse still underlines the command in red implying that it doesnt know that annotation:

[image: ml]

What am I doing wrong?
This is a webservice which will be consumed by a SOAP Client later.

I also cant use **@Transient**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that annotation is [contained in xml-apis.jar](https://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html)? I mostly find it in jaxb-api.jar or jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar files - and having a look at [xml-apis-2.0.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.jar) there isn't even a javax.xml.bind folder let alone javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient.

Comment: @Thomas thanks you can post that as answer. BTW, am I using the correct annotation for what Im trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

As already stated in my comment, you're importing the wrong jar. There are a couple of online services that help in finding all jars that contain a certain class, e.g. http://findjar.com (ideally you'd refer to the documentation related to that class first).

Using that service you'll see that the jars containing `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient` are mostly named `jaxb-api.jar` or have the keyword `bind` on their names: https://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html

Additionally, if you're having problems even after importing the jar you think you need, you can peek inside that jar with some zip viewer (e.g. 7zip). That way you should be able to see that xml-apis.jar contains folders `javax/xml/parsers` and `javax/xml/transform` but no `javax/xml/bind` - so it must be the wrong file.

Btw, "I downloaded xml-apis.jar from mvnrespository" sounds like you're handling dependencies manually. If that's the case I suggest having a look into build tools such as Maven or Gradle.